# WebOS 3.0 Access to UI from function

Tags: javascript, television, webos, enyo

I cannot access to enyo Ui component from function:onComplete in WebOS 3.0.

```
buttonTapped: function(inSender, inEvent) {
    console.log("Button is clicked");
    this.$.txt.setContent(inSender.name + " tapped."); // This worked
    var request = webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.tv.systemproperty", {
        method: "getSystemInfo",
        parameters: {"keys": ["modelName", "firmwareVersion", "UHD", "sdkVersion"]},
        onComplete: function (inResponse) {
            var isSucceeded = inResponse.returnValue;
            if (isSucceeded){
               console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(inResponse));
               $.txt.setContent("Result: "+JSON.stringify(inResponse)); // This is not worked
            }
        }
    });
...
```

Console output

```
Button clicked
Result{"modelName":"WEBOS1","firmwareVersion":"03.00.00","UHD":"false","sdkVersion":"03.00.00","returnValue":true} 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'txt' of undefined
```

I not found any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your callback function is not executing in the context of your component.  `this` is not your component (not to mention you're missing the keyword `this` in front of `$.txt...`).

What you need to do is bind the context of the callback function or use it to create a closure over a variable that contains a reference to `this`.

This is a such a common occurrence that Enyo provides a utility method for this:   `this.bindSafely`.

Try the following:

```
onComplete: this.bindSafely(function (inResponse) {
    var isSucceeded = inResponse.returnValue;
    if (isSucceeded){
        console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(inResponse));
        this.$.txt.setContent("Result: "+JSON.stringify(inResponse));
    }
})
```

See:  http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/#/kind/enyo/CoreObject/Object:bindSafely